# Why I get this error installing python venv software?

Tags: python, python3, mint

I'm quite new to linux and python and I'm trying to install a python software ([openmotor](https://github.com/reilleya/openMotor)) in a python virtual enviroment as the author recommends to do it but I'm getting this error message when trying to install required packages.

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt

Collecting appdirs
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting cycler
  Using cached cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting decorator
  Using cached decorator-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
Processing /home/daniel/.cache/pip/wheels/56/ea/58/ead137b087d9e326852a851351d1debf4ada529b6ac0ec4e8c/docopt-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ezdxf
  Using cached ezdxf-1.0.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
Collecting imageio
  Using cached imageio-2.26.1-py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.7.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (9.2 MB)
Collecting networkx
  Using cached networkx-3.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.24.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.3 MB)
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-9.4.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.3 MB)
Collecting pyparsing
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting pyqt-distutils
  Using cached pyqt_distutils-0.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.8 kB)
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/daniel/openMotor/.venv/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpnkx3pbua prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpbc53w75u
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-n21cyx0e/PyQt5
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/tmpnkx3pbua", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/tmpnkx3pbua", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/tmpnkx3pbua", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/tmp/tmpnkx3pbua", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
      File "/tmp/tmpnkx3pbua", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zzcpxk69/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zzcpxk69/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zzcpxk69/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 585, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-n21cyx0e/PyQt5/project.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zzcpxk69/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zzcpxk69/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 236, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zzcpxk69/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/daniel/openMotor/.venv/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpnkx3pbua prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpbc53w75u Check the logs for full command output.
```

The software is being developed in Python 3.10 but my venv is running 3.8 I guess as it is my main python instalation could it be the cause? if not, any tips in how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: missing libraries perhaps?  I installed it with apt: `sudo apt install python3-pyqt5` but you are using a virtual env.  Maybe that will install the libraries you need to build it as well.

Comment: What OS/release are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the program `qmake` isn't on your `PATH` (hat tip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72046110). If it isn't on your system, you may be able to install it via:

`sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake`

The virtual environment is a good idea, as it isolates your *python* dependencies for this project. But `pyqt` has dependencies outside of the Python ecosystem.

Comment: Thank, it helped to remove the error, but now it gets stuck in ` Preparing wheel metadata ... - ` and doesn't show anything else.

Would preciate some advice with that.

Comment: My first thought would be to ensure `wheel` is installed (via `pip install wheel`). 
But I see comments about having to confirm the license for PyQT [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73714829/pip-install-pyqt5-it-cannot-go-on) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73818706). It looks like the syntax would be `pip install pyqt5 --config-settings --confirm-license=`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, but it didn't work for me.  However I solved it uninstalling the pip version provided by the developer of the software I was trying to install an installing a more recent verision in the same virtual enviromen, the procedure is explained here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69333000/pip-hangs-on-installing-packages  if it could help someone.